# Google cloud messaging (GCM) library not found in Android SDK manager

Tags: java, android

I want to implement push notification in my android app .So i wanted to install Google cloud messaging library from the android SDK manager.But i dont see it in the Extras section of the sdk manager.Some people suggested that updating the sdk manager will make the GCM library visible.Others suggest that the GCM library is deprecated and i just need to use Google play services library.Which one among the two is true and how do i fix the issue?

Comment: Use the Google play services library, it contains the GCM classes

Answer (score 0):

You will be having Google play services library.Use that one.It works best for push notification

Answer (score 0):

**According to the official documentation**

To write your client application, use the GCM APIs. To use this API, you must set up your project to use the Google Play services SDK, as described in Setup Google Play Services SDK.

Caution: When you add the Play Services library to your project, be sure to add it with resources, as described in Setup Google Play Services SDK. The key point is that you must reference the library—simply adding a .jar file to your Eclipse project will not work. You must follow the directions for referencing a library, or your app won't be able to access the library's resources

**Refer this link**
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Mark as up if this information is useful for you.